# How do I stop getting ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to append each line of data to a dataframe for my course. I entered in

```
search_word = "liberty"
results_data = []

for key in text_dictionary:
    word_counts = Counter(text_dictionary[key].split())
    search_count = word_counts[search_word]
    file_names = key
    main_author = ecco_metadata_w_counts.loc[ecco_metadata_w_counts["DocName"] == key]["Author 1"].values[0]
    title = ecco_metadata_w_counts.loc[ecco_metadata_w_counts["DocName"] == key]["Title"].values[0]
    results = {'file_names':file_names,'Author 1':main_author,'title':title,'search_word':search_word,'search_count':search_count}
    results_data.append(results)
results_df = pd.DataFrame(results_data)
```

and I keep getting the result

```
ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

What does this error mean and how can I fix this?
This is the whole error report.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-119-d60594554fc3> in <module>
      6     search_count = word_counts[search_word]
      7     file_names = key
----> 8     main_author = ecco_metadata_w_counts.loc[ecco_metadata_w_counts["DocName"] == key]["Author 1"].values[0]
      9     title = ecco_metadata_w_counts.loc[ecco_metadata_w_counts["DocName"] == key]["Title"].values[0]
     10     results = {'file_names':file_names,'Author 1':main_author,'title':title,'search_word':search_word,'search_count':search_count}

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    893 
    894             maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
--> 895             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
    896 
    897     def _is_scalar_access(self, key: Tuple):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1109 
   1110                 if hasattr(key, "ndim") and key.ndim > 1:
-> 1111                     raise ValueError("Cannot index with multidimensional key")
   1112 
   1113                 return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)

ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

`ecco_metadata_w_counts` is this:
[`ecco_metadata_w_counts` 2nd half](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKzhM.png)[`ecco_metadata_w_counts` 1st half](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ank6.png)

Comment: Whenever you ask what an error means, also give a stack trace.  Which line is the error on?

Comment: Have you tried googling the error message? It finds lots of other SO questions that show how to fix it.

Comment: what does ecco_metadata_w_counts look like? Can you give an example?

Comment: Can you give some data to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I just added two screenshots of ecco_metadata_w_counts.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer. It was having good internet. I was staying in a place with bad internet and the second I went to a place with good internet, everything worked. I'm sorry for wasting everyone's time.